# Je (me) brosse les dents

Tags: déterminants, possessif, pronoms-réfléchis

> Je **me** brosse **les** dents.

Cette phrase est correcte.

D'après ce [fil](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/41196/is-tu-brosses-tes-cheveux-correct), il est possible de dire :

> Je brosse **mes** dents.

La deuxième réponse de ce fil dit qu'il est impossible d'omettre *me* dans la première phrase et de ne pas remplacer *les* par *mes*.

> Je brosse **les** dents.

Mais je ne comprends pas pourquoi. À mon avis, les trois options devraient être correctes :

> Je **me** brosse **les** dents.
>
> Je brosse **les** dents.
>
> Je brosse **mes** dents.

*Je brosse **les** dents* devrait sous-entendre que je brosse **mes** dents.

Answer (score 3):

L'explication au TLFi est utile :

> **Rem.** (sur la construction réfléchie). Selon l'usage habituel quand il s'agit de compléments d'objet désignant des parties du corps,
> l'adjectif possessif réfléchi est remplacé par l'article défini,
> l'idée réflexive étant exprimée par le pronom correspondant employé en
> fonction du complément indirect : *je brosse mes dents, il brosse ses
> cheveux* remplacés par : *je me brosse les dents, il se brosse les
> cheveux.*
>
> [ *Trésor de la langue française informatisé* (TLFi), « [brosser](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/brosser) ». ]

La marque du possessif, peu importe sa forme, semble donc nécessaire dans un tel cas. Sans aucune idée de possessif (*Je brosse les dents*) la phrase serait cohérente mais incomplète à mon avis et je ne ressens pas du tout qu'il s'agirait des dents de la personne qui brosse et sans voir ce que la personne fait j'attendrais donc la fin de la phrase ou une précision de mon interlocuteur et il y aurait possiblement un court silence...

Answer (score 0):

Je brosse les dents *de quelqu'un d'autre ou d'un animal*, par exemple.

Je brosse *les cheveux de ma fille*, par exemple.

Sans pronom pronominal (Je brosse *me* cheveux, ou, Je *me* brosse les cheveux), cela change le sens puisqu'il faut dire **de qui**: ma fille, mon fils.

Voir le lien dans la question pour la réponse avec le pronom pronominal *me*.